# boost asio streambuf garbage after all data received from client

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm writing a small boost asio tcp server and client that sends and receives plain text. The communication is more or less request response. During testing I figured I'd just spam the server with data, sending it 100.000 requests.

The message sent from the client to the server:

> \n=BEGIN 1,test\n
>   Hello World: 1
>   \n=END\n

In the above message the counter goes from 0 to 99.999 (in the above example it is 1 as in "BEGIN 1" and "Hello World: 1").

As stated, this works fine and all 100.000 messages are received by the server, but once all is transferred, the read-handler is invoked up to several times more, although no data is sent from the client.

Reading the data from the streambuf object yields remnants of older messages as in:

> IN 61868,test\n
>   Hello World: 61868
>   \n=END\n

And:

> =END\n
>   =END\n

The weird thing is that it only seems to happen when the number of messages exceeds a certain amount, but it's not consistent, leading me to believe there is some overflow or UB going on somewhere, and as such I clearly have done something wrong, but I cannot seem to be able to figure out what. The code for reading is:

```
 typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::streambuf>       asio_streambuf_ptr;
 typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> asio_socket_ptr;

 ...

 void on_read(const asio_socket_ptr& s, const asio_streambuf_ptr& b,
     const boost_error_code& e, size_t length) {

   if ( !e ) {

       std::string temp(boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(b->data()), length);
       //process temp

       b->consume(length);
   } else {
       //Handle the error - or close the socket if disconnected
       handle_error(s, e);
   }

   read(s, b);
 }

 void read(const asio_socket_ptr& s, const asio_streambuf_ptr& buf) {

     if (s->is_open()) {
       boost::asio::async_read_until(*s, *buf, "\n=END\n",
           boost::bind(on_read, s, buf, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
             boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
     }
 }
```

My first implementation of the on_read function used std::istream and std::getline to read each message line by line, but the problem was present there as well, and since the streams are hard to inspect in gdb i rewrote it to make it easier to look into.

Now I must stress that I am new to boost-asio, and that this is my first attempt at making something useful with that part of boost, and as such I do accept that I could well be missunderstanding several of concepts of the asynchronous io system.

So my question: Has anyone experienced this before or have any suggestion to what I'm doing wrong?

I've made an SSCCE, but as it involves a fair amount of code being a server and a client, I think I'll wait to post it here until someone requests it.

**Update:**
The issue seems to be that the client writes messages faster than the server can read them. Throttling the client slightly fixed the issue. Note: Changing the internal buffer sizes did not help, so it seems that the client flooded some os-network buffers or something to that effect.

Comment: Another thing that you shouldn't do is pass your `boost::shared_ptr` by reference. Just pass them by value, so that the reference count can work properly, especially with async operations where you can't be certain that at the time the handler is called, the original object is still alive.

Comment: Yes, that is in general right, although in the code I can guarantee for the lifetimes of these shared_ptrs, it is better to pass them by value - it will also be less confusing to whoever ends up maintaining this code :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't continue reading in case of an error -> only when no error is detected.
Perhaps you continue reading after the EOF?
Move the call to read in the function on read in the if.

Comment: It does not continue reading, upon an error like EOF, the socket is closed and in the read function the socket is checked if it's open and if it's not open, the read function just returns. There are no boost errors during the test-run.